# Fastest iteration and display image based on data?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listbox

i have a sql database with 10000+ entries that's filled within a wpf listbox. i'd like to display an image based on an integer within a column of the table.  i only have >10 choices for each integer, so i only need @ 10 images.

the question i have is, if a user scrolls down the listbox, what's the fastest way to link up an image to a value using c# and wpf?

i'd rather not use the address of the image in the column, as storage of the data is at a premium, i'd rather just match it.

here's what i mean:

someInt  |  SomeData

(DisplaySomeImageHere) | thisWouldBeTheNumber1
 (DisplayOtherImageHere)    | thisWouldBeTheNumber2
 etc.

but i have thousands of entries.  what would be the best way to scroll these and add the image the fastest way?

Comment: no, you guys don't get the question.  it's not "what's the fastest way to populate the listbox", it's "what's the fastest way to match an image to a value from the sql database, then put it in the listbox?"

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to retrieve data from the SQL is by using the native SqlDataReader.

To display data, if you have a lots of items (10,000+ is consider a lots) you should check virtual mode.

Check out this other question:

[How do I populate a ListView in virtual mode asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336901/how-do-i-populate-a-listview-in-virtual-mode-asynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

To speed up scrolling in addition to [Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx) (which is on by default in ListBox) you should use [Container Recycling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.virtualizationmode.aspx).

```
<ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```

This should speed up scrolling because you won't be destroying containers as you scroll them out of view.